# How to fetch mutiple values on select option and display in input type using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to fetch mutiple values from database using ajax php.
I've a select option(value is fetching from database), and if i select any option then i want to display the related data which is matching with the `id`
of the the current option.but currently i'm able to fetch only one data column from databse.
I'm writing my current code please have a look at it and let me know how can i modify it.

My select option:-

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Vehicle..." class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="-1" name='vno' onChange="getCity(this.value);" id="vno"  required='true' >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
        foreach($results as $vd) { ?>

    <option value='<?php echo $vd['id'];?>'><?php echo $vd['vno'];?></option>";

    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

and the js file

```
// Fetch city from Database
function getCity(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "retrive_data.php",
        data:'id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#rate").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

retrive_data.php

```
<?php
require_once ("dbController.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if (! empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_vehicle WHERE id = '" . $_POST["id"] . "' ";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>

<?php
    foreach ($results as $city) {
        ?>
<option value="<?php echo $city["rate"]; ?>"><?php echo $city["rate"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It’s not clear from your code what `$(“#rate”)` is.  I’m not sure exactly what result you’re getting, either. But I would suggest a couple of changes to your code that will save you some grief later: 1) your query is wide open to injection. Research prepared statements and start using them immediately. 2) when using ajax, don’t send html; send a JavaScript object by setting the responding scripts header to json and using json_encode(). Doing this will make it much easier to work with the data in the browser.

Comment: `$(“#rate”)` - i'm using this id to display the fetched data. this is the only one data that i can fetch using the above query.

Comment: There is no input or select with that id in the code you presented. Are you trying to fill a single input, or a select?  But more importantly, what are you receiving back from your ajax call, and what do you expect?

Comment: I have an answer started, but I’ll have to pick it up tomorrow

Comment: @TimMorton, I'm trying to fill mutiple input type. Means when `id` matches from the table row then i want to fetch particular row data in input.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js code as below

```
  // Fetch city from Database
    function getCity(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "retrive_data.php?id=" + val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#rate").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No. Sending the id in the query string is not at all the right answer. The receiving script won’t even recognize it because it is looking for post variables.

Answer (score 0):

I’m making some assumptions about the desired result, and I’m not sure what the connection is between vehicles and city rates... but there are multiple issues here.  Let’s work through them:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Vehicle..." class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="-1" name='vno' id="vno"  required='true' >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php foreach($results as $vd): ?>
    <option value="<?= $vd['id']?>" ><?= $vd['vno'] ?></option>";
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<!-- add a landing spot for the data coming in -->
<select id="rate"></select>
```

Nothing major here, just took out the onChange (typical practice is to have a listener in the JavaScript. Separation of concerns)

In your JavaScript, I don’t think you were successfully passing the id. It should be a JavaScript object. Also, send `data` to a function that knows how to put the data in your form:

```
// Fetch city from Database
function getCity(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "retrive_data.php",
        data:{id: val},
        success: function(data){
            showRate(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Monitor the select for a change. (JavaScript should be inside document ready block)

```
$('#vno').on('change', function (){
    getCity($(this).val());
});
```

Function to display the results of your ajax call:

```
showRate(data) {

    // this lets you see the data that was returned 
    console.log(data);

    var rate = $('#rate');

    // clear current content 
    rate.html('');

    // create options, assuming this is a select 
    $.each(data, function() {
        rate.append($("<option />").val(this.rate).text(this.rate));
    });
}
```

retrieve.php

Need to use prepared statements, and sending data as json instead of html is recommended

```
<?php

// sending json (data), not html (presentation)
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once ("dbController.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if (! empty($_POST["id"])) {

    // substituting variables in a query is a big no-no
    // $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_vehicle WHERE id = '" . $_POST["id"] . "' ";

    // must use placeholders / prepared statement 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_vehicle WHERE id = ?'";

    // check your database object for how to do prepared statements and row fetching. If it doesn’t do prepared statements, dump it!
    $stmt = $db_handle->prepare ($query);
    $stmt->execute($_POST["id"]);

    $out = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $rate = $row['rate'];

        $out[] = array(
            'rate'=>$rate
        );
    }

    die(json_encode($out));
}
```

Caveat:  all code is off the top of my head, and typed on a phone. Syntax errors are likely. This is intended to show concepts and ideas for further research